# Throwing a custom exception in Async sub is not handled in a Try Catch

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, exception, task

I noticed something strange and cannot find why this wouldn't work correctly.

The error i'm experiencing is in a Async sub where a exception is thrown:

```
Private Async Sub Test1
    If Await SomeAsyncReadProcess <> "My Result" then
        Throw New Exception("Onoo invalid result!")
    End if
End sub
```

Then Higher up the code if have this Sub in a Try Catch. Now the strange thing is then when i Throw the new exception my debugger stops and says `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException`. When i revert the sub back to a SYNC sub without the Aynsc/Await then everything works as it should.

Comment: Google "async void considered harmful" to find good hits.

Comment: Thanks this pointed me in the right direction! I changed it to a Async Function of type Boolean.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot easily catch exceptions from an `Async Sub`. This is by design, as `Async Sub` methods are very unusual `Async` methods that act like top-level event handlers. The general rule is ["avoid `async void`" (or in this case, `Async Sub`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

The appropriate fix is to change `Async Sub` to `Async Function ... As Task`.